# Query to retrieve custom columns from select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Let's say that within the customers table there are the following columns : `customer_id` and `customer_name`.

From a select statement that I am trying to perform, I need to add in a custom `sysdate` column that is not associated with the customer's table and give it a value. I tried using an inner query, but that only led to the creation of the `current_date` column but it has no value.

Example -

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL) AS CURRENT_DATE
FROM customers
```

OUTPUT

```
CUSTOMER_ID || CUSTOMER_NAME || CURRENT_DATE
-----------    -------------    ------------
1              JOHN DOE          
2              JANE DOE
```

The expected output I am trying to get is down below - Could anyone please provide me a solution to this problem?

OUTPUT

```
CUSTOMER_ID || CUSTOMER_NAME || CURRENT_DATE
-----------    -------------    ------------
1              JOHN DOE          08/07/2020
2              JANE DOE          08/07/2020
```

Comment: How many rows are in your `dual` table? Also be careful referring to `current_date` as there is also a built-in function with that name. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html

Answer (score 2):

In my database, it is as simple as

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sysdate
  2  from emp
  3  where rownum < 4;

     EMPNO ENAME      SYSDATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
      7369 SMITH      07.08.2020 22:13:22
      7499 ALLEN      07.08.2020 22:13:22
      7521 WARD       07.08.2020 22:13:22

SQL>
```

Your query works as well (although, why making it more complex than it should be?):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, (select sysdate from dual) current_date
  2  from emp
  3  where rownum < 4;

     EMPNO ENAME      CURRENT_DATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
      7369 SMITH      07.08.2020 22:14:35
      7499 ALLEN      07.08.2020 22:14:35
      7521 WARD       07.08.2020 22:14:35

SQL>
```

---

Why didn't you get the result? No idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date using SYSDATE, so you could do something like

```
SELECT 
  CUSTOMER_ID, 
  CUSTOMER_NAME,
  to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS cust_date
FROM 
  customers
```

which should give you the output formatted how you want.